# Is there a way to track our website activity from our Facebook fans clicking link on our page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, ads

We just started an advertisement with Facebook and are curious if there is a way to track who has visited our website by clicking our website link on our Facebook page?  I am very pleased with all of the ways to track the performance of our ad on Facebook and want to see if people are not only 'liking' our page, but visiting our website to learn more about us.  Any information would be helpful :)

This is our website if you need to look into it further:

http://drkennethlevine.webs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much you can change about your website or how it is built. However there is a way to track where the users who visited your page from. Use the http reffer field.

In php (and probably in most other languages) you can get the refer link by using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

The refer field contains the last page visited by the user.

Simply count the number of users that are surfing from your facebook page to your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` as mentioned by @fake, or simply use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), which will provide you a lot of statistics for free, including referers, stats by browsers, countries...

All you have to do is create a GA account, and link your website to your account (you'll have a few javascript lines to add in your footer for it)